# Over voltage protection IC keeps burning

Tags: power-dissipation, damage, over-voltage-protection

I am currently working on a project where over voltage protection is necessary. I made a test circuit using an LP5300 (SOT23-6 type.)

https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1912111437_LOWPOWER-LP5300B6F_C387703.pdf

I supplied it with 5V and I used an LED (140mA-measured) without a resistor for a first test. For a second test I use the same LED with 3K resistor in series with it.

According to the datasheet it should also protect against over-current (2.5A) but I kept burning out the IC in the first test. During the second test it did not burn out. I assume this is because of the lower power dissipation, as a consequence of the 3K resistor. According to the datasheet, tests were conducted by the manufacturer with 5V input, and 2A current (\$R_{DS}\$ On graph.)

**Question:**

How is it possible that I can't even pull 140mA through without it burning out (0.7W power dissipation) but they achieved 5V 2A results? What am I missing? Can I achieve 5V 2A with this IC at all?

I would really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Did you use the recommended capacitors? How do you know the LED current was only 140mA?

Comment: Yes i did. 1 uF caps as the document suggests. And i measured the LEDs current consumption with a multimeter. My confusion comes from the fact that at 5v 2A you would not have 0.45W thermal dissipation which apparently is the max for this type. But then how did the manufacturer do that test i referred to? Im probably just misinterpreting the documentation somehow

Comment: Your comment implies you're using the SOT-23 version but your question implies the SOT-89 version. If the former, did you connect all the GND leads?

Comment: Im using the SOT-32. I did indeed connect all the ground leads (these i tested with continuity to confirm). And regarding the thermal dissipation, i am referring to SOT-32s data. This has a max thermal dissipation of 0.45W. If i used 140mA at 5V that would lead to a thermal dissipation of 0. 7W, therefore exceeding the maximum and burning the component. How can a protection ic handle 2A at 5V if its thermal dissipation is exceeded well before that? If it cant, why is the graph showing otherwise?

Comment: Actually the IC dissipation when 'on' @140mA should be about 0.13\$\Omega\$ * 0.14A^2 = 0.0025W. I don't see any way to figure your problem out from the information given.

Comment: I forgot that the ic isnt actually dropping voltage. So your power dissipation calculation is correct. I would add that its probably less than 0.0025W at 140mA because the Rds would be less. Rds was 130mOhm at Iout=1A

Comment: Are you sure about the 140mA of the LED ? I could have understand a lack of reliability of those kind of components if you were applying a huge amount of current  (short circuit for example). But a burning out at 140mA ? It seems strange. Which LED drives 140mA @5V by the way ?

Comment: The LED i used from an old arduino kit i had laying around. Im not sure if the ic burns out or not, but it certainly doesnt work after the above mentioned test. Just to point out i use a solder temp of 230 deg C to minimise thermal damage to the leads. What i noticed is that when i use the arduinos 5V supply and connect the circuit up that way the system works fine without a resistor. But when i use the 5V 2.5A supply (leftover from raspberry pi) then it lights up for a split second and then doesnt work anymore. Really stuck on this problem

Comment: I think what might be happening is that the leads heat up so much during the soldering that they must burn away a little, and after applying 140mA causes just enough heat for them to completely separate. I just tried an other test. The first time it worked fine (no resistor) then the wire broke away from the solder. So i fixed it but afterwards the circuit didnt work. Tried a continuty test and the leads showed an open. Perhaps i need to try soldering with a finer tip

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to contact issue when using the 5V 2.5A supply. I used a usb type b micro connector for easy plug in. The connector had contact problems leading to the inconsistant operation. Thanks for the help everyone!